# How can i add google map to a component that is using sightly?

Tags: google-maps, aem, sightly

I have a component called `foo`

I have `foo.html` in `apps/foo/components/content/foo/foo.html`

currently this file contains the following.

```
<div  data-sly-use.ev="Foo"
        class="${ev.cssClass || ''}"
        title="${ev.title || ''}"
        data-emptytext="Foo Asset">
        ${ev.html @ context='unsafe'}</div>
```

I have `Foo.java` in `apps/foo/components/content/foo/Foo.java`
 that has `getCssClass(), getTitle(), getHtml()` needed by foo.html.

The above works fine

**Question**

When the user adds this component to the page, I want it to include a google map in the page. The lat/long to the google map will be provided by `Foo.java#getLat()` and `Foo.java#getLong()`

How can I do this?

I have the google map working in an HTML outside of AEM and the code is pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the lat/long values for `myLatlng` variable in the above javascript will need to come from `Foo.java`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass parameters to a script you can do as they generally do in Coral UI via data-xxx attributes in the Sightly script.

- Set the property from your Foo into a data attribute in some DIV you will later fetch in JS.
- Get the div in JS via its ID and obtain the data attributes you are interested in.

Example:

Sightly

```
<div id="map_canvas" data-lat="${ev.lat}" data-long="${ev.long}">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
this.mapCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("map_canvas")[0];
var lat = $mapCanvas.data("lat");
var long = $mapCanvas.data("long");
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
```

I hope this helps! :)